# How to convert vtk file to numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I voxelize the STL file with the program below and save it as a vtk file.

The code itself is fine, as the program below works fine. 　
However, I want to convert it to numpy.array format and save it in npz format as well. Using vtk_to_numpy doesn't work, what should I do?

The ultimate goal is to convert it to numpy.array format and use it for 3d deeplearning.

e.g.
Taking 3*3*3 voxel data as an example,

I want to generate np.array with shape (3,3,3) like below

```
[
 [[0,0,0],
  [0,1,0],
  [0,0,0]]
 [[1,1,1],
  [1,1,1],
  [0,0,0]]
 [[1,1,1],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]]
]
```

```
import vtk
import time
import numpy as np
import vtk.util.numpy_support as vnp

########　data ########
filename_in = "<your STL>.stl"
filename_out = "out.vtk"
mesh_size = 100
tol = 1e-7
cubicORrect = "rect"
##################################

start = time.time()

reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename_in)
reader.Update()

closed_poly = reader.GetOutput()

# x_min:0 x_max:1, y_min:2,y_max:3,z_min:4,z_max:5
bounds = closed_poly.GetBounds()
max_size = max([bounds[1] - bounds[0], bounds[3] -
                bounds[2], bounds[5] - bounds[4]])
cell_dims = [mesh_size, mesh_size, mesh_size]  # x, y, z

if cubicORrect == "cubic":
    mesh_pitch = [max_size/cell_dims[0],
                  max_size/cell_dims[1],
                  max_size/cell_dims[2]]
else:
    mesh_pitch = [(bounds[1] - bounds[0])/cell_dims[0],
                  (bounds[3] - bounds[2])/cell_dims[1],
                  (bounds[5] - bounds[4])/cell_dims[2]]

mins = [bounds[0], bounds[2], bounds[4]]


px, py, pz = mesh_pitch
mx, my, mz = (cell_dims+np.array([1, 1, 1])) * mesh_pitch  # max
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
coords = np.stack(np.mgrid[:mx:px, :my:py, :mz:pz], -1).reshape(-1, 3) + mins
points.SetData(vnp.numpy_to_vtk(coords))

structured_base_mesh = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid()
structured_base_mesh.SetExtent(
    0, cell_dims[0], 0, cell_dims[1], 0, cell_dims[2])
structured_base_mesh.SetPoints(points)

append = vtk.vtkAppendFilter()
append.AddInputData(structured_base_mesh)
append.Update()
base_mesh = append.GetOutput()

cell_centers = vtk.vtkCellCenters()
cell_centers.SetInputData(base_mesh)
cell_centers.Update()

poly_points = cell_centers.GetOutput()

select_enclosed = vtk.vtkSelectEnclosedPoints()
select_enclosed.SetInputData(poly_points)
select_enclosed.SetSurfaceData(closed_poly)
select_enclosed.SetTolerance(tol)
select_enclosed.Update()

isInsideOrOutside = select_enclosed.GetOutput(
).GetPointData().GetArray("SelectedPoints")
structured_base_mesh.GetCellData().AddArray(isInsideOrOutside)

threshold = vtk.vtkThreshold()
threshold.SetInputArrayToProcess(
    0, 0, 0, vtk.vtkDataObject.FIELD_ASSOCIATION_CELLS, "SelectedPoints")
threshold.SetInputData(structured_base_mesh)
threshold.ThresholdBetween(0, 1)
threshold.Update()

writer = vtk.vtkDataSetWriter()
writer.SetFileName(filename_out)
writer.SetInputData(threshold.GetOutput())
writer.Update()

nparray = vnp.vtk_to_numpy(threshold.GetOutput().GetCellData().GetArray("SelectedPoints"))
```

Comment: A dataset is more than one array : which one do you want to save ? Coordinates ? Data ? Cells ?  And then what "doesnt work" means ?

Comment: Thanks. @NicoVuaille
 read the vtk docs about Coordinate, Data and Cells and understand a bit. I think what I want is Data format.

My goal is to create data from the STL file in the same format as modelnet10.npz from https://modelnet.cs.princeton.edu/#.

I added it to the question text.

Comment: ”doesnt work”  means  vtk_to_numpy(threshold.GetOutput()) or

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create the 3d shaped numpy array:

- get the vtkDataArray you want. Something like `threshold.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArary(<arrayname>)`
- turn it into numpy array using `vtk_to_numpy`. This returns a 'flat' array: 1D list of all values
- reshape it according the the mesh dimensions (`threshold.GetOutput().GetDimensions()`)

Inspirated from this answer https://discourse.vtk.org/t/convert-vtk-array-to-numpy-array/3152/4

Comment: Thanks.
I modified your code to get the ndarray I wanted

# GetPointData <- GetCellData
vnp.vtk_to_numpy(threshold.GetOutput().GetCellData().GetArray("SelectedPoints"))

Answer (score 0):

```
import vtk
import time
import numpy as np
import vtk.util.numpy_support as vnp

########　data ########
filename_in = "<your STL>.stl"
filename_out = "out.vtk"
mesh_size = 100
tol = 1e-7
cubicORrect = "rect"
##################################

start = time.time()

reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename_in)
reader.Update()

closed_poly = reader.GetOutput()

# x_min:0 x_max:1, y_min:2,y_max:3,z_min:4,z_max:5
bounds = closed_poly.GetBounds()
max_size = max([bounds[1] - bounds[0], bounds[3] -
                bounds[2], bounds[5] - bounds[4]])
cell_dims = [mesh_size, mesh_size, mesh_size]  # x, y, z

if cubicORrect == "cubic":
    mesh_pitch = [max_size/cell_dims[0],
                  max_size/cell_dims[1],
                  max_size/cell_dims[2]]
else:
    mesh_pitch = [(bounds[1] - bounds[0])/cell_dims[0],
                  (bounds[3] - bounds[2])/cell_dims[1],
                  (bounds[5] - bounds[4])/cell_dims[2]]

mins = [bounds[0], bounds[2], bounds[4]]


px, py, pz = mesh_pitch
mx, my, mz = (cell_dims+np.array([1, 1, 1])) * mesh_pitch  # max
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
coords = np.stack(np.mgrid[:mx:px, :my:py, :mz:pz], -1).reshape(-1, 3) + mins
points.SetData(vnp.numpy_to_vtk(coords))

structured_base_mesh = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid()
structured_base_mesh.SetExtent(
    0, cell_dims[0], 0, cell_dims[1], 0, cell_dims[2])
structured_base_mesh.SetPoints(points)

append = vtk.vtkAppendFilter()
append.AddInputData(structured_base_mesh)
append.Update()
base_mesh = append.GetOutput()

cell_centers = vtk.vtkCellCenters()
cell_centers.SetInputData(base_mesh)
cell_centers.Update()

poly_points = cell_centers.GetOutput()

select_enclosed = vtk.vtkSelectEnclosedPoints()
select_enclosed.SetInputData(poly_points)
select_enclosed.SetSurfaceData(closed_poly)
select_enclosed.SetTolerance(tol)
select_enclosed.Update()

isInsideOrOutside = select_enclosed.GetOutput(
).GetPointData().GetArray("SelectedPoints")
structured_base_mesh.GetCellData().AddArray(isInsideOrOutside)

threshold = vtk.vtkThreshold()
threshold.SetInputArrayToProcess(
    0, 0, 0, vtk.vtkDataObject.FIELD_ASSOCIATION_CELLS, "SelectedPoints")
threshold.SetInputData(structured_base_mesh)
threshold.ThresholdBetween(0, 1)
threshold.Update()

writer = vtk.vtkDataSetWriter()
writer.SetFileName(filename_out)
writer.SetInputData(threshold.GetOutput())
writer.Update()

nparray = vnp.vtk_to_numpy(threshold.GetOutput().GetCellData().GetArray("SelectedPoints"))
```